# How to solve "invalid anonymous type member decelerator" error

Tags: c#, urlhelper

I have created an Extension function for UrlHelper which simplifies the writing of parameters. It just accept two string parameters and return a string of desired format. In my case it work like this:

```
public static string CustomAction(this UrlHelper helper, string key, string value)
{
    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode("(" + key + "=" + value + ")");
}
```

The problem I am facing now is when I use this function inside the URL.ACTION more than once it gives me an "invalid anonymous type member decelerator" error.
Can someone tell me how can I solve this problem?

Example:

```
Url.Action("someAction", "someController", new { where = Url.CustomWhereAction("user.ID", Url.UrlParams("id")), Url.CustomWhereAction("person.ID", Url.UrlParams("id")) })
```

Just to clarify:

```
Url.UrlParams()
```

is another Extension function which avoids the programmer to write the code for extracting the routeData values.

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, your syntax makes no sense.  What property name are you trying to create?

Comment: Don't try to put all of this on one line; at a minimum, add in line breaks at appropriate places.  If you do that, your syntax error should make itself much more apparent.  If that isn't enough, then break it up into multiple statements.  The smaller the statement, the less likely you are to have syntax errors, and the easier they'll be to find.

Comment: Well, I have found the problem I need to give a property some name. Like:
new 
{ where = Url.CustomWhereAction("user.ID", Url.UrlParams("id")), AND = Url.CustomWhereAction("person.ID", Url.UrlParams("id")) 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have

```
Url.Action("someAction", "someController", new {
 where = Url.CustomWhereAction("user.ID", Url.UrlParams("id")), 
 Url.CustomWhereAction("person.ID", Url.UrlParams("id"))
})
```

this is invalid syntax you mean

```
Url.Action("someAction", "someController", new {
 where = Url.CustomWhereAction("user.ID", Url.UrlParams("id")), 
 where2 = Url.CustomWhereAction("person.ID", Url.UrlParams("id"))
})
```

Comment: No, the below part is right. Property name must be declare. In this case both "where" and "where2" are property names.

Comment: yes but in your code you dont have the second name, you have the first code I show, with where but no where2

Comment: Yes, the second part of is right. Mine code is wrong.